# DAX calculated table column error - PBI Desktop ADDCOLUMNS() to CALENDARAUTO()

Tags: powerbi, dax

I trying to create a DAX calculated table in PBI Desktop using `ADDCOLUMNS()` to `CALENDARAUTO()` table. All of the calculated columns work great, except a random few of the calculations have a problem with using the `[Date]` columns and give an error:

> Column 'Date' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression.
>
> Parameter is not the correction type

**This calculation (plus a dozen others) are successfully computed:**

- "SortDesc_Date"

```
"SortDesc_Date", - DATEDIFF(date(9999, 12, 31), [Date], DAY)
```

**These 3 calculations fail:**

- "Mo_startDate"

```
"Mo_startDate", STARTOFMONTH([Date])
```

- "Yr_startDate"

```
"Yr_startDate", STARTOFYEAR([Date])
```

- "SortDesc_YrMo"

```
"SortDesc_YrMo", - DATEDIFF(date(9999, 12, 31), STARTOFMONTH([Date]), MONTH)
```

---

Does anyone have any clues why these columns have computation errors?

[image]

[image]

---

SCRIPT (Updated)

*Working after correcting columns to substitute the usage of time intelligence functions.*

```
Calendar (v3) = 
-- var_MoName = FORMAT([Date], "MMM")
-- var_MoStartDate = EOMONTH([Date],-1) + 1
ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALENDARAUTO (),
    "DateKey", FORMAT([Date], "YYYY") & FORMAT([Date], "MM") & FORMAT([Date], "DD")
    , "Year", YEAR([Date])
    , "Mo", MONTH([Date]) 
    , "day", DAY([Date])
    , "Mo Name", FORMAT([Date], "MMM")
    , "Mo-Yr", FORMAT([Date], "MMM") &"-"& FORMAT([Date],"YY")
    , "Mo_startDate", EOMONTH([Date],-1) + 1
    , "Yr_startDate", DATE(YEAR([Date]),1,1)
    , "Qtr", QUARTER([Date])
    , "Qtr Name", "Qtr " & FORMAT([Date], "Q")
    , "Yr Name", "YR " & FORMAT([Date], "YYYY")
    , "Mo_endDate", EOMONTH([Date],0) 
    , "SortDesc_YrMo", - DATEDIFF(date(9999, 12, 31), EOMONTH([Date],-1)+1, MONTH)
    , "SortDesc_Date", - DATEDIFF(date(9999, 12, 31), [Date], DAY)
    , "Date (DESC)", [Date]
    , "Mo-Yr (DESC)",  FORMAT([Date], "MMM") &"-"& FORMAT([Date],"YY")
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[STARTOFMONTH](https://dax.guide/startofmonth/) and [STARTOFYEAR](https://dax.guide/startofyear/) are Time Intelligence functions that expect a date *column* as the first argument rather than a single date value. They are designed to work in measures to manipulate filter context rather than on single date values.

You can use the following definitions instead:

```
"Mo_startDate", EOMONTH ( [Date], -1 ) + 1

"Yr_startDate", DATE ( YEAR ( [Date] ), 1, 1 )
```